# software to analyze my own database of games with statistics

Tags: analysis, software, database

I've been playing on lichess.org for my online games, and is the primary way I enjoy chess. One of the big reasons why I started playing on lichess.org was that they offer a simple way to export your games from their database into pgn format.

So far playing casually I have logged over 250 games at this point and downloaded the pgn files. I'm interested in getting some statistics out of this data. Is there a chess database application that I could use?

The primary goal of analyzing these games en mass is that I want to identify my strengths and weaknesses with my game openings. For example I enjoy playing the queens gambit, but I'd like to know my win percentages with it. Which ECO codes I am currently struggling with, which variants am I coming against most often? Am I truly a tactical player? or a positional player?

I believe that the data can help me identify trends in my game that I am currently unaware of.

I already use engines like crafty and stockfish to help me analyze individual games, but I'm having difficulty finding tools to help me analyze my entire collection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you get a lot, most, if not all of those statistics right from lichess? You can go to: https://lichess.org/insights/<username> and generate them.

Comment: @Tommiie at the time of your comment this is true, at the time that I posted this, it was not. lichess has gotten some amazing features over the years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few programs - commercial (Chessbase, Hiarcs) or free (ChessX, Scid, Scidb, ChessDB, Arena). More or less, all will provide what you need.

I personally prefer ChessX (under MacOS and Windows) using the following steps:

- Open your database
- Select Menu View->Players which enables the player explorer
- Filter the games for your own name

You will get a statistics for each ECO code played with White or Black.
Now you can tell, which ECOs provide good or poor results. If you need further details or statistics, you can create a ticket on ChessX homepage.

Answer (score 4):

The most popular chess database software is ChessBase. You can open the pgn of your games with ChessBase, and there are functions that produce opening statistics, e.g. the number of times you have faced the Semi-slav/Meran/Moscow-Botvinnik as white, as well as your percentage score against these variations.

ChessBase can also be seen as a GUI for engines, so you can also use your favourite engine (Stockfish/Crafty/Houdini/Komodo) to analyse your games within the program. There is also the "LiveBook", which is essentially a giant opening book stored on the ChessBase servers, as well as computer opening books which tell you which moves are objectively the strongest (but not necessarily most practical --- this is actually for the reference of the engine).

Comment: I can vouch for chessbase, which is great for opening analysis and lots of other useful things.  Definitely worth the money.

Comment: If you import your games into a Chessbase opening book (ctg), it will show you the performance elo rating for the various moves in your opening repertoire.